# Loading div from external site in Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

TLDR: How can I show #div from another URL inside Electron app.

I'm learning javascript and I've came across this problem. I wanted to load specific div from another website inside electron app. Already tried looking for the solution online and reading docs, but that failed.
I've tried using javascript with this:

```
$("#test_div-in_electron").load("https://some-website.com #test-div-on-webpage")
```

with scripts in index.html:

```
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
<script src="../app/resources/js/renderer_main.js"></script>
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

And it shows - nothing. blank div.

Comment: @TomDoodler Yep, I did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is called a Cross Origin Request:

> A web application makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource >that has a different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.
>
> An example of a cross-origin request: The frontend JavaScript code for
>   a web application served from http://domain-a.com uses XMLHttpRequest
>   to make a request for http://api.domain-b.com/data.json.
>
> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the
>   Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web
>   application using those APIs can only request HTTP resources from the
>   same origin the application was loaded from, unless the response from
>   the other origin includes the right CORS headers.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

In Electron, you can disable this security on opening the main window:

```
new BrowserWindow({
  ..
  webPreferences: {
    ..
    webSecurity: false
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Now I need to figure out why it fails to load data from second server.